# SSRS 2005: Dynamic Background Color for Cells, Excluding Subtotal Cells

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have an expression in place in my report to change the cell color if the value of the cell is above a certain threshold.  It's just an expression setup in my text box called "percent" - on the background color property.  Looks like this:

```
    =IIf((FormatPercent(Sum(Fields!items.Value)/First(Fields!totalItems.Value),2) >= .04 & "%" 
And First(Fields!errorCodeAdjType.Value) = "Error1")
Or (FormatPercent(Sum(Fields!items.Value)/First(Fields!totalItems.Value),2) >= .02 & "%" 
And First(Fields!errorCodeAdjType.Value) = "Error2")
,
"Maroon", "Transparent")
```

It works as I want it to; however, it is also changing color of my subtotal cells.  How can i write this better to make sure it doesn't think that one of my subtotal cells meets the cell color criteria?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the background property individually for different cells. Sounds like you've defined this for multiple cells. Clear the BackgroundColor property for the cells that are in the subtotal row.

If you don't have a separate subtotal row defined in the report, then you'll need to add a condition that can distinguish subtotal rows from detail rows. I strongly recommend that you create the subtotals by using SSRS groups, not as subtotal rows included in the query. That is, avoid `WITH ROLLUP`.